Error when writing DataFrame to Cassandra using Spark: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging
I'm encountering an issue when trying to write a DataFrame from Apache Spark to Cassandra. Here's the setup:
I'm running Apache Spark version 3.3.3 in standalone mode on my local machine (bigdatapc). I have a DataFrame named routesDF that I'm trying to write to a Cassandra table. The DataFrame schema looks like this:
routesDF.printSchema()
root
 |-- airline: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airline_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- source_airport: string (nullable = true)
 |-- source_airport_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- destination_airport: string (nullable = true)
 |-- destination_airport_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- codeshare: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stops: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- equipment: string (nullable = true)

To write this DataFrame to Cassandra, I'm using the following command in the Spark shell:
routesDF.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .option("keyspace", "practica")
  .option("table", "routes")
  .mode("Append")
  .save()

And I have created this table in Cassandra
cqlsh:practica> CREATE TABLE routes (
    source_airport text,
    destination_airport text,
    distance int,
    PRIMARY KEY (source_airport, destination_airport)

However, I'm encountering the following error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/Logging
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)

It seems like there's an issue with the spark-cassandra-connector library. I've already included the JAR file spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.3.0.jar in the bin/spark-shell command when starting the Spark shell, so I'm not sure why I'm still getting this error.
bin/spark-shell --master spark://bigdatapc:7077 --driver-memory 2G --executor-memory 2G --total-executor-cores 2 --executor-cores 1 --jars postgresql-42.7.3.jar,spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.3.0.jar

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried to change the jar file to a more recent version, spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.5.0.jar, and to assembly version, spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.5.0.jar. Both tries unsuccessful.
The error with the first one is the same as the one I already presented, but with the latter I got this:
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.connector.write.streaming.StreamingWrite.useCommitCoordinator()Z

  at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraBulkWrite.useCommitCoordinator(CassandraWriteBuilder.scala:116)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:366)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.writeWithV2$(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:353)

  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.AppendDataExec.writeWithV2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:244)



NoClassDefFoundError usually indicates there's an issue with the classpath and/or running software components which are incompatible. Instead of supplying the connector JAR, I would recommend just specifying the package coordinates (with --packages) so that all the necessary dependencies are included at runtime.
The quickest way to troubleshoot your problem is to do an isolation test. Start a Spark shell with just the minimum options. For example:
$ bin/spark-shell \
  --master <spark_master_url> \
  --spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra_host_ip \
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.3.0
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions

If your Cassandra cluster has authentication enabled then you will also need to supply the credentials with:
  --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=<cassandra_role>
  --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=<cassandra_password>

For all other configuration options, see the Configuration Reference page.
It's important to note that you can only use version 3.3 of the connector to run with Spark 3.3. The Spark Cassandra connector 3.5 is only works with Spark 3.5. See the Spark Cassandra connector compatibility table for details. Cheers!
